# Get Authenticated User Laravel/Lumen Passport

Tags: php, laravel, oauth, lumen, laravel-passport

I am using lumen to build my api and passport for api authentication.

I have my users info all recorded in a users table whereas the user's password is stored in another table(login) - *(one to one relationship)*.

Everything is working fine with the authorization *(i can create the bearer token and get access to the auth:api middleware with it)* but the problem is that once i get logged in with the bearer token i cannot get the authenticated user's info.

I tried

```
Auth::user();
$request->user();
Auth::guard('auth')->user();
```

But all these function returns **null**

**Please help me to access the authenticated user.**

**web.php**

```
$router->group(['prefix' => 'dev', 'namespace' => 'Dev'], function ($router) {
    //Generates Bearer Access Token for api access
    $router->post('accessToken', 'TestController@createAccessToken');

    //protected api
    $router->group(['prefix' => 'auth', 'middleware' => 'auth:api'], function ($router) {
        $router->get('authenticated-user', 'TestController@getAuthenticatedUser');
    });
});
```

TestController.php

```
public function getAuthenticatedUser(Request $request)
{
    //die('test');
    dd(Auth::user());//returns null
}
```

Comment: Are you accessing these functions inside of a route protected by the `auth:api` middleware?

Comment: yes inside the auth:api middleware   @patricus

Comment: Can you show your routes and controller code?

Comment: question now contains routes and controller code

Comment: Sorry, missed that you were using lumen. What steps did you take to get passport setup in lumen?

Comment: https://github.com/dusterio/lumen-passport used this to make the laravel passport work on lumen also since my password for the user is stored in another table i had to use validateForPassportPasswordGrant($password) this function to make it work

Comment: Everything worked now the only problem is that i cannot access the authenticated user once i pass the auth:api middleware with a bearer token

Answer (score 1):

did you already use Illuminate\Http\Request?
or Dingo\Api\Http\Request?

```
function getAuthUserData(Request $request){

    $userDt=$request->user();

    return $userDt;
}
```

this working for me

Answer (score -1):

Based on documentation for Laravel Lumen 7.x you can use Auth::user() or $request->user() to get the authenticated user as long as you pass the token with the url [Lumen Doc](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication)

Comment: The solution you are giving is not using passport.

Comment: I am pretty sure this is correct because this is what I am using but also if i try e var_dump($request->user()) or dd($request->user()) i get null or no response (I have no idea why) but if I use var_dump($request->user()->id) i get current user id.